# How to use other speech recognition service on my Nexus 5 device?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, nexus-5

This is not a technical question. I hate the way that the speech to text engine on my nexus 5 (running version 6.02) puts out certain words, and I'd like to change it.

I tried to change it from Settigs->Language and Input, however i cant find it. I don't even know where to look. I don't even know if this is possible! If it is, then I'd appreciate some guidance :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it eyes-free service?

Comment: yes buddy, i want to change eyes free sr motor

Comment: If it's not a technical question, what does it do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the speech recognition service setting changed in Android v6. It is now located in:

```
Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps -> Assist & voice input -> Voice input
```

Furthermore, make sure that "Assist app" is not set to "Google App", otherwise you cannot change the "Voice input" as this setting will not even appear.